# React axios request in ComponentDidMount not passing data as props to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, lifecycle

Hi guys I can't see my Error here hope someone can hlep...
This is my fetch Data class:

```
  export default class Auftrag extends Component {
        state = {
            auftraege: "Test",
        };

        getAuftraege = () => {
            axios.get("Auftraege/auftraege").then(e => {
                this.setState({
                    auftraege: e.data,
                });
                console.log(e.data);
            });
        };

        componentDidMount() {
            this.getAuftraege();
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <>
                    <AuftragDisplay test={this.state.auftraege} ></AuftragDisplay>
                </>
            );
        }
    }
```

And this is my constructor in my Display class:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props);
    }
```

The axios Request is getting fired and I get the right data in my console. But It is not getting passed to my Component. 
Hope someone knows whats wrong and can help me

SOLVED:
Thx to san I tried it and could solve the problem. I got the data passed but console.log() was called before the update so I got the old data. THX again

Comment: what are you getting in your `AuftragDisplay` component? when you are trying to print the props from `Auftrag` component

Comment: HI, Im getting: {test: "Test"} so the testvalue I assigned

Comment: You should try console.log(props) in componentDidUpdate and use react devtool for check props of component.

Comment: Yes thx san I tried it and could solve the problem. I got the data passed but console.log() was called before the update so I got the old data. THX again

Comment: hey, @TimSchuetz have you tried consoling e ? whether the response is coming from the url??

Comment: @TimSchuetz are you getting any error? because your posted code is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. you can see below same code with different api as an example

```
class Auftrag extends Component {
        state = {
            auftraege: "Test",
        };
        getAuftraege = () => {
            axios
            .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
            .then(e => this.setState({auftraege: e.data}))
        };
        componentDidMount() {
            this.getAuftraege();
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <>
                    <AuftragDisplay test={this.state.auftraege} ></AuftragDisplay>
                </>
            );
        }
    }
    const AuftragDisplay = ({test}) =><h2>Hi--->{test.title}</h2>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put the state inside constructor of Auftrag class, I should work.

Comment: I tried, but its not working:  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            auftraege: "Test",
        };
    }

Comment: @Ajay Hi, in a class based component you can either write inside the constructor or without it. There is no compulsion.